# Moving automatically Physics Platform (the better way?)

Tags: coronasdk, platform

I have some platforms ("static Object") where my player jump ("Dynamic Object") onto them to get coins.
I would like know what the better way to make moving my physics platform automatically on the screen ?
 Is it the transtition.to() the only way to do that ? Or the Velocity could do it ? Or something else ?

Thanks for your reply, I need really to know that to goahead in my game.

Answer (score 0):

When its the case to move physics objects, transition.to() is not recommended. You can simply create a method, which will work in enterFrame and change the position of the object. If you encounter some problems, you can try to change object types of the platforms to "Kinematic".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dude,
At last, I'm using the velocity and the "kynematic" physic, that's the best way and the easiest I think.

Because transition.to that's so hard with physics